# Sorting array items in php with multiple dependencies from the same array

Tags: php, sorting, dependencies

I have a component dependency array in PHP which needs to be sorted in correct order such that a component can only be rendered when its parent components are rendered i.e; It must be sorted in a way that on each index the ids in parent field must refer to lower than current index of the same array **Is there any iterator in PHP that can sort this type of array?** Following is a sample list:

**parent field contains multiple ids from the same list*

```
[{"id":"docBody","parent":[]},
{"id":"top","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"header_border_container","parent":["top"]},
{"id":"header_left","parent":["header_border_container"]},
{"id":"header_center","parent":["header_border_container"]},
{"id":"system_toolbar","parent":["header_center"]},
{"id":"Notifications_Button","parent":["Notification_Dialog","system_toolbar"]},
{"id":"User_Menu_Button","parent":["system_toolbar","User_Menu"]},
{"id":"User_Menu","parent":["header_center"]},
{"id":"User_Menu_LogOut","parent":["User_Menu"]},
{"id":"User_Menu_Change_Password","parent":["User_Menu","User_Menu_LogOut"]},
{"id":"Notifications_Store","parent":["header_center"]},
{"id":"left","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"menu_accordian","parent":["left"]},
{"id":"ScreenContainer","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"InfoDialog","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"ID_BC","parent":["InfoDialog"]},
{"id":"InfoDialogContent","parent":["ID_BC"]},
{"id":"change_password_dialog","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"toaster","parent":[]},
{"id":"Notification_Dialog","parent":[]},
{"id":"Notifications_Grid","parent":["Notification_Dialog","Notifications_Store"]}]
```

**Sorted array:**

```
[{"id":"docBody","parent":[]},
{"id":"toaster","parent":[]},
{"id":"Notification_Dialog","parent":[]},
{"id":"top","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"left","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"ScreenContainer","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"InfoDialog","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"change_password_dialog","parent":["docBody"]},
{"id":"header_border_container","parent":["top"]},
{"id":"header_left","parent":["header_border_container"]},
{"id":"header_center","parent":["header_border_container"]},
{"id":"system_toolbar","parent":["header_center"]}, ...
```

Comment: What's an example of how it should be sorted?

Comment: It must be sorted in a way that on each index the ids in parent field must refer to lower than current index of the same array

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the array and add to output array only those elements that already have all parents in there. If there are any elements left - repeat.

For this sample you provided it took 2 runs. If in any run no element was added to the output array it means that there is an error in the input data and this tree cannot be solved.

```
<?php

$ds = [["id"=>"docBody","parent"=>[]],
["id"=>"top","parent"=>["docBody"]],
["id"=>"header_border_container","parent"=>["top"]],
["id"=>"header_left","parent"=>["header_border_container"]],
["id"=>"header_center","parent"=>["header_border_container"]],
["id"=>"system_toolbar","parent"=>["header_center"]],
["id"=>"Notifications_Button","parent"=>["Notification_Dialog","system_toolbar"]],
["id"=>"User_Menu_Button","parent"=>["system_toolbar","User_Menu"]],
["id"=>"User_Menu","parent"=>["header_center"]],
["id"=>"User_Menu_LogOut","parent"=>["User_Menu"]],
["id"=>"User_Menu_Change_Password","parent"=>["User_Menu","User_Menu_LogOut"]],
["id"=>"Notifications_Store","parent"=>["header_center"]],
["id"=>"left","parent"=>["docBody"]],
["id"=>"menu_accordian","parent"=>["left"]],
["id"=>"ScreenContainer","parent"=>["docBody"]],
["id"=>"InfoDialog","parent"=>["docBody"]],
["id"=>"ID_BC","parent"=>["InfoDialog"]],
["id"=>"InfoDialogContent","parent"=>["ID_BC"]],
["id"=>"change_password_dialog","parent"=>["docBody"]],
["id"=>"toaster","parent"=>[]],
["id"=>"Notification_Dialog","parent"=>[]],
["id"=>"Notifications_Grid","parent"=>["Notification_Dialog","Notifications_Store"]]];

$sds = [];

while (count($ds) > 0) {
  echo 'left: '.count($ds).PHP_EOL; 
  foreach ($ds as $k => $d) {
    $add = true;
    foreach ($d['parent'] as $parent) {
      if (!isset($sds[$parent])) {
        $add = false;
      }
    }
   
    if ($add) {
      $sds[$d['id']] = $d;
      unset($ds[$k]);
    }
  }
}


var_dump(array_values($sds));
```

Output:

```
left: 22
left: 2
array(22) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "docBody"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(3) "top"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "docBody"
    }
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(23) "header_border_container"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(3) "top"
    }
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(11) "header_left"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "header_border_container"
    }
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(13) "header_center"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(23) "header_border_container"
    }
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(14) "system_toolbar"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "header_center"
    }
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(9) "User_Menu"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "header_center"
    }
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(16) "User_Menu_LogOut"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "User_Menu"
    }
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(25) "User_Menu_Change_Password"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(9) "User_Menu"
      [1]=>
      string(16) "User_Menu_LogOut"
    }
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "Notifications_Store"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(13) "header_center"
    }
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(4) "left"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "docBody"
    }
  }
  [11]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(14) "menu_accordian"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(4) "left"
    }
  }
  [12]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(15) "ScreenContainer"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "docBody"
    }
  }
  [13]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(10) "InfoDialog"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "docBody"
    }
  }
  [14]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(5) "ID_BC"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(10) "InfoDialog"
    }
  }
  [15]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(17) "InfoDialogContent"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(5) "ID_BC"
    }
  }
  [16]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(22) "change_password_dialog"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(7) "docBody"
    }
  }
  [17]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(7) "toaster"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [18]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(19) "Notification_Dialog"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  [19]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(18) "Notifications_Grid"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(19) "Notification_Dialog"
      [1]=>
      string(19) "Notifications_Store"
    }
  }
  [20]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(20) "Notifications_Button"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(19) "Notification_Dialog"
      [1]=>
      string(14) "system_toolbar"
    }
  }
  [21]=>
  array(2) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(16) "User_Menu_Button"
    ["parent"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      string(14) "system_toolbar"
      [1]=>
      string(9) "User_Menu"
    }
  }
}
```